# how to add execute batch commands for existing jenkins jobs using groovy script

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy

I have more than 100+ Jenkin jobs. But I have a new requirement where I have to include additional windows batch command to all the jobs without removing/disturbing the existing configurations.

Is there any way to inject the new execute command to all the jobs in jenkins master.

Could some one shed light on this please

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, a word of caution, these scripts modifies the underlying structure in the running Jenkins instance, take a backup before doing this!

You can execute the following scripts in the "Script Console" found under "Manage Jenkins" (you need admin access)

The following script inserts a batch command as the first step in all of the free style jobs:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import hudson.tasks.BatchFile;

for (job in Jenkins.getInstance().getAllItems(FreeStyleProject.class)) {
  def buildersList = job.getBuildersList()
  def oldBuilders = new ArrayList(buildersList); // Take a copy of existing steps so that we can insert them later
  buildersList.clear() // We need to clear the list first, add at index is not supported
  buildersList.add(new BatchFile("""\
  echo "Windows batch command"
"""));
  buildersList.addAll(oldBuilders)
  job.save();
}
```

And the following inserts it at the end:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import hudson.tasks.BatchFile;

for (job in Jenkins.getInstance().getAllItems(FreeStyleProject.class)) {
  def oldBuilders = job.getBuildersList().add(new BatchFile("""\
  echo "Windows batch command"
"""));
  job.save();
}
```